# At X's expense and of X's timber

Tags: idioms, british-english

The following string appears in Jenks, E. "The prerogative writs in English law" *Yale Law Journal* 32:6 (1923):

> ...the accused in the meanwhile [was] to be kept in one of the new
>   gaols ordered...to be built...in every county, in some borough or
>   royal castle, at the King's expense, and if possible of the King's
>   timber.

What does it mean for a prisoner to be lodged "at the King's timber"? Does it mean that the King pays for firewood?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the misreading of *[constructed] **of** the King's timber*. The quoted text doesn't say ***...at** the King's timber*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Re-read the sentence. The *of* refers to the gaols, not the prisoner. It means that the jails (gaols) are to be built of the King's timber (wood).

Comment: +1 And the gaols are likewise to be built at the King's expense. The King's timber is timber drawn from forests belonging to the King --

Comment: @StoneyB precisely.

Comment: yes, that clears it up. it did seem odd to me that a mediaeval king would be feeding the prisoners!